# custom log file for angular 2/4 project

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-services, logfile

I need to add a log file to my angular 2 projects which stores info, error log in the file like log.txt file
how to create **service which creates and write log to file using typescript**

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this in the frontend? You won't have access to it.

Comment: yes for this is for frontend for typescript error for log

Comment: this is for tracking info log and error on front-end framework made by (angular, typescript, and node ) for testing and storing log

Comment: The thing is that you can‘t change data in the client‘s file system.

Comment: so there is any way to log typescript error log to server side?

Comment: I‘d recommend to create an api endpoint in your backend which takes strings with errors and saves them. A different solution would be to save the errors in the localStorage of the browser (Google it) - depending on how much stuff you save that can get quite slow though (don‘t use this for prod).

Comment: do you have any idea about this https://romakita.github.io/ts-log-debug/#/appenders/file?id=configuration

Comment: No I don't know that library. I think it's for backend logging. You could send a http request to your api (backend/server), which logs stuff with the library you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159995/discussion-between-amit-singh-rawat-and-sandrooco).